# Edittext won't loose focus on backpressed

Tags: android

```
@Override
public void onBackPressed() {
    if (text_editor_edit.hasFocus()) {
        text_editor_edit.clearFocus();
    } else {
        super.onBackPressed();
    }
}
```

It takes two back-press two get the editText  out of focus.
Is there a way to use only one back-press to get editText out of focus?
I tried checking if the keyboard is open and on back press apply the same logic as above ,but not working.
Thank You!

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
    @Override
    public void onBackPressed() {
        if (text_editor_edit.hasFocus()) {
            // hide virtual keyboard
            InputMethodManager imm = (InputMethodManager)getSystemService(Context.INPUT_METHOD_SERVICE);
            imm.hideSoftInputFromWindow(text_editor_edit.getWindowToken(), 0);
        } else {
            super.onBackPressed();
        }
    }
```

Comment: I may have forgot to mention that on first backpress the keyboard is closed
And according to your code the activity will close and get back two the previous activity

Comment: yes, i understood, did you try my answer yet or not?

Comment: Yes. The main reason I think is that the keyboard is a different application and the first back press is not applicable for my app.

Comment: try the answer first and check , let me know then

Comment: I tried. It does not work. 
That's what "yes" replies to.